# What are the charts that make up an atlas for the long line?

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology

This question is prompted while I was working through the MIT OCW (Massachusetts Institute of Technology, Open CourseWare) for 18.965, ``Geometry of Manifolds,'' in its Lecture 2,

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-965-geometry-of-manifolds-fall-2004/lecture-notes/lecture2.pdf

Near verbatim, the setup for the example of a long line from there is this:

Let $S_{\Omega}$ denote the smallest uncountable totally ordered set.

Consider the product $X = S_{\Omega} \times (0,1]$ with dictionary order topology.

Give $X$ charts as follows.

$\forall \, (\omega, t) \in X$, \
if $t\neq 1$, let $U_{(\omega,t)} = \lbrace \omega \rbrace \times (0,1)$ and

$\begin{aligned}                                                                                              
  & \phi_{(\omega,t)}: U \to \mathbb{R} \\                                                                    
& \phi_{(\omega,t)}(\omega,t) = t                                                                             
\end{aligned}$

If $t=1$, ``let $S(\omega)$ denote the successor of $\omega$.''

Set $U_{(\omega,1)} = \lbrace \omega \rbrace \times (0,1]\text{sup}\lbrace S(\omega) \rbrace \times (0,1)$ and

$
\phi_{(\omega,t)}(\eta, t) = \begin{cases} t & \text{ if } \eta = \omega \\
  t + 1 & \text{ if } \eta = S(\omega) \end{cases}
$

My questions are the following: what is the domain for that second chart, $(\phi_{(\omega,t)}, U_{(\omega,1)}\
)$? It's unclear to me if this is a union or what's going on with the supremum for $S(\omega)$.

Also, in this context, could someone give an example of what it means to be a successor for $\omega$, to clarify what it means, and in general?

Thanks, and for those working through MIT OCW 18.965 or are seriously interested in learning differential topology online, I'm keeping a blog with my progress and some, hopefully helpful, thoughts, discussions, and solutions at ernestyalumni.wordpress.com.

Mrowka, Tomasz. 18.965 Geometry of Manifolds, Fall 2004. (MIT OpenCourseWare: Massachusetts Institute of Technology), http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-965-geometry-of-manifolds-fall-2004} (Accessed 29 Nov, 2014). License: Creative Commons BY-NC-SA

Comment: Comparison with the [Wikipedia treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology)) suggests that you want $S_\Omega$ to be the "smallest" uncountabel *well-ordered* set, ie. the least uncountable ordinal.  Imposing "totally ordered" is not sufficient to make the definition unique.

Comment: Although this question is already quite old, I would like to comment that the definition given in the MIT lecture notes is NOT one of the usual definitions of the Long Line.Usually you take the half open interval [0,1[ which is closed on the left and open on the right.This is not just a minor difference,this space has totally different properties.The usual Long Line is connected but not metrizable while this space in the MIT notes is NOT connected and my guess is that it is just a fancy way to write down the disjoint union of uncountably many copies of the real line-so it should be metrizable.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the first comment above, the set $S_\Omega$ is well ordered. Modern notation usually has $\omega$ as the first infinite ordinal, and $\omega_1$ as the first uncountable ordinal (same as $S_\Omega$), but I will stick with the notation as used in the above question (in which $\omega$ may be an arbitrary element of $S_\Omega$).

For any $\omega\in S_\Omega$ consider the set $\{\xi\in S_\Omega : \xi > \omega \}$. Since this set is non-empty (since $S_\Omega$ has no last element), and since $S_\Omega$ is well-ordered, the set $\{\xi\in S_\Omega : \xi > \omega \}$ must have a minimal element, and this is what is denoted by $S(\omega)$ in your question, the successor of $\omega$. So, $S(\omega)=\min\{\xi\in S_\Omega : \xi > \omega \}$.

For the case when $t=1$ on one hand you have the half-open interval $I=\lbrace \omega \rbrace \times (0,1]$ and following it you have the open interval $J=\lbrace S(\omega) \rbrace \times (0,1)$. Note that in the dictionary order if $U=I\cup J$, then $U$ itself may be thought of as an interval, namely if $a=\inf I$, $b=\sup I = \max I = \langle \omega,1 \rangle$, $c=\inf J$, and $d=\sup J$, then $U=(a,d)$, but also $U=(a,b]\cup (c,d)$. In fact if you unravel the definition of $\inf$ you would realize that $c=b$, so when you look at $U=(a,b]\cup (c,d)$ there is no gap in between $b$ and $c$, so you could really think of it as just one interval $U=(a,d)$ where 
$a=\inf\Bigl(\lbrace \omega \rbrace \times (0,1]\Bigl)$, $d=\sup\Bigl(\lbrace S(\omega) \rbrace \times (0,1)\Bigr)=\langle S(S(\omega)),0 \rangle$ (think of the latter equality), and this interval is a "usual" neighborhood of $b=c=\max \Bigl(\lbrace \omega \rbrace \times (0,1]\Bigl)= \langle S(\omega),0 \rangle= \inf\Bigl(\lbrace S(\omega) \rbrace \times (0,1)\Bigl)$ which is "in the middle" if the interval. (If some part of this is unclear please keep reading.)

What $\phi_{(\omega,t)}$ does is that it sends the interval $I=\lbrace \omega \rbrace \times (0,1]$ onto the interval $(0,1]$ in the real line, and it sends 
the interval $J=\lbrace S(\omega) \rbrace \times (0,1)$ onto $(1,2)$ in the real line. Of course $(0,1]\cup (1,2) = (0,2)$ is a usual neighborhood of the number $1$ in the real line. So the map $\phi_{(\omega,t)}$ makes it so that $(a,d)$ (in the notation introduced above) is a usual neighborhood of $b=c=
\langle \omega, 1 \rangle = \langle S(\omega), 0 \rangle$. I am abusing notation since $\langle S(\omega), 0 \rangle$ was never introduced formally in the definition in your question, since $\langle S(\omega), 0 \rangle \not\in \lbrace S(\omega) \rbrace \times (0,1]$,
but you could think of $\langle \omega, 1 \rangle$ as what 
$\langle S(\omega), 0 \rangle$ "should be".